# If condition not working when one variable is more than 100000

Tags: javascript

I have 2 variables a and b in JavaScript.
I have one condition:

```
 if(a>b){alert('error')}
```

This condition is working perferctly fine.
But when b>=1 lakh, control is going inside if irrespective of the value of a.
What can be the possible solution?

Sample code:

```
    var a = amt1;
    var b = amt2;
    if(a>b){
    alert('error');
    }
```

error is thrown when b>=100000 irrespective of value of a.

Comment: What *are* the values? Are they *strings* by chance? `"2" > "1000000"` is true.

Comment: If both are numbers then it will work for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you have a or b as String..if so u could handle it with following code:

```
var a = parseFloat(amt1);
var b = parseFloat(amt2);
if(a>b){
   alert('error');
}
```

Comment: same thing, just a little shorter: `if (+amt1 > +amt2)`

Comment: Thanks buddy. The issue was because the format of the amounts were different.
Changing the condition as below will do the trick.
    if(parseInt(a) > parseInt(b)){